Using Mathematica to perform matrix operations which depend on variables
I need to compute a group relator for a group presentation. In particular,
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 1/a
\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w
\end{pmatrix}, $$ where $a$ is nonzero and the determinant of $B$ is 1. I need to expand this matrix mutiplication
$$A^{-2}BAB^{-3}ABA^{-1}B^{-2}$$ in terms of coordinates $(a, x,y,z,w)$,
I have tried MatrixFunction but it seems only works with one matrix as a variable, and here I have two. Could you help? Thank you.

Try: ma = {{a, 0}, {0, 1/a}}; mb = {{x, y}, {z, w}}; MatrixPower[ma, -2] . mb . ma . MatrixPower[mb, -3] .   MatrixPower[ma, -1] . MatrixPower[mb, -2]

Hi, can you submit this as an answer so I can accept your answer? Doing it term by term instead of a functions work for me. Also can you tell me how to incorporate the condition wx-yz=1 and simplify the answer?

You can use MatrixPower for exponentiation as:
ma = {{a, 0}, {0, 1/a}}; 
mb = {{x, y}, {z, w}}; 
res= MatrixPower[ma, -2] . mb . ma . MatrixPower[mb, -3] .   MatrixPower[ma, -1] . MatrixPower[mb, -2]

To simplify and use w x-y z=1 you may write:
Simplify[res, w  x - y  z == 1 ]



Thank you, this is very helpful.

I suggest that you expand the matrix multiplication $(A^{-2}BAB^{-3}ABA^{-1}B^{-2})$ in terms of the coordinates $((a, x, y, z, w))$ using the following code. This code defines the matrices $A$ and $B$, computes the inverses, and performs the matrix multiplications step-by-step. Here is an attempt to do this which may help you:
(* Define matrices A and B *)
A = {{a, 0}, {0, 1/a}};
B = {{x, y}, {z, w}};

(* Compute inverses of A and B *)
Ainv = Inverse[A];
Binv = Inverse[B];

(* Define the expression *)
expr = Ainv.Ainv.B.A.Binv.Binv.Binv.A.B.Ainv.Binv.Binv;

(* Simplify the expression *)
SimplifiedExpr = Simplify[expr]

(* Output the result *)
SimplifiedExpr



